# Building ember.js fails on OS X 10.8.2

Tags: javascript, rake, ember.js, bundler

On a Mac OS X system (10.8.2), with these tools installed:

- Ruby, 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0], via brew
- Bundler, 1.2.3 via `gem install bundler`
- rake, 10.0.3 via `gem install rake`

It is not possible to build Ember from source. Below is the error log when running `rake dist`:

```
± ~/dev/ember.js (master ✓) ⚡ rake dist
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25: warning: redundant nested repeat operator
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/Users/foo/dev/ember.js/Rakefile:3:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

± ~/dev/ember.js (master ✓) ⚡ rake dist --trace
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25: warning: redundant nested repeat operator
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/foo/dev/ember.js/Rakefile:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:583:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

From having a look at the Ember Data build instructions and discussion in #emberjs, it seems that you need to run `bundle` first. Doing so successfully installs a handful of bundles, though it prompts at the end for an admin password “to install the bundled RubyGems to your system”.

If you then run this command to see what gems are installed, you can see that one gem in particular refuses installation. Running `bundle install` as advised doesn’t address this problem.

```
± ~/dev/ember.js (master ✓) ⚡ bundle exec rake -T
https://github.com/pangratz/github_downloads.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

A suggestion from Twitter was to run `bundle rake dist`. This produces:

```
± ~/dev/ember.js (master ✓) ⚡ bundle rake dist
Could not find task "rake".
```

And another for `bundle exec rake dist`:

```
± ~/dev/ember.js (master ✓) ⚡ bundle exec rake dist
https://github.com/pangratz/github_downloads.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

Running `bundle install` at this point installs the list of gems but **asks for an admin password** at the end and reports success. One thought from #emberjs was that this means it's installing gems into my system and not a sandboxed environment and *that* is the true problem here.

What can be done to overcome this bundle/rake error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a solution that worked for me:

```
cd <your ember clone>
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
rvm install 1.9.3
rvm use 1.9.3
rvm rubygems latest
bundle install
rake dist
```